# How to fix a poblem with lodash configuration?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I installed lodash in terminal and wrote this code:

```js
// import _ from './node_modules/lodash/lodash.js';
import * as _ from './node_modules/lodash/lodash.js';
const myListTest = [
    'water',
    'apple'
]

const myNewArray =_.last(myListTest)
console.log(myNewArray)
```

When I use following code with `import * as _ from './node_modules/lodash/lodash.js';`I got an error  `Uncaught TypeError: _.last is not a function at script.js:8:21`

When I use commented code `import _ from './node_modules/lodash/lodash.js';` I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/lodash/lodash.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at script.js:1:8)`

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try `const last = require('lodash/last')` and using it like `last(myListTest)`?

Comment: Ive got then error: require is not defined. Maybe its because I've tried to configure my project to ES6 as I have that requirements but I have no idea

Comment: How are you running this script?

Comment: Ohh. Thanks! I was running it only from browser but it seems that it works while runing in node.js